# How to get notified about a closed session in PHP

Tags: php, session, notifications, session-timeout

I am keeping a list of active users of my web site.
When user logs in I add them to the list.

Then I periodically (on timer) call  a PHP script which delays PHP session expiration time on the server each time by 10 mins.

When users logs out I remove them from the active users list.
As timer is stopped and an expiration is not delayed anymore, a PHP session expires after 10 mins.

So far so good.

When user closes a browser without logging out, their session still expires after 10 mins as a time stamp is not updated anymore.

**But this user still remains in my active users list !!**

How can I remove this user?

I am keeping this list in order to prevent users from entering from 2 computers simultaneously, that is a client requirement.

EDIT:
I am sure that this can be done as bank sites, ticket sites etc. somehow cope with this problem.

Comment: roll your own session handler. then the expiration will be purely up to **YOUR** code and you can do whatever updates/cleanups you want: http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is you can't. Not with PHP alone anyway. If you are happy to force javascript usage, you could write a script which would 'poll' the server from the user's browser on very regular intervals to let it know the user was still active.. you would then also reduce the interval set for your PHP script to keep things updated with more accuracy.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. However when browser is closed, I can't call nothing.

Comment: But if you are expecting the client to 'check in' with the server on a regular basis, as soon as that interval is exceeded you can assume the browser is closed/session ended and remove the user from the active list. If using javascript to alert the server this interval could be set to around 30 seconds, wouldn't that be accurate enough?

Comment: I still don't understand you. The browser is closed, no JavaScript. PHP session will expire automatically. Where exactly can I remove the user??

Comment: 1. Browser polls server, and updates a 'last-active' timestamp for the client's IP in the list of active users.  2. Your regularly run PHP script checks the time difference between the current time and each 'active user's' last active timestamp. 3. If the interval is found to be greater than 30 seconds or whatever, have the PHP script remove this user from the active list

Comment: Again, This is exactly how things work. Till the browser is closed. How can I run PHP script after the browser is closed? There are no timers in PHP. Are you suggesting a cron job or something like that?

Comment: Yes, sorry.. I assumed you were using a CRON job for the regularly executed PHP file. Alternatively, the poll script itself could check if the user is still active/authenticated

Comment: Well, at least we understand each other :-) Seems like kind of a cron job is my only option. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try updating the "active users" list on a more frequent basis, but it would generally make more sense to clear a user's session data upon each login. Therefore, if a second login occurs from another computer, the first one is terminated upon the next page load.

Comment: I cannot see how increasing frequency can help me. And I can't throw a user out just because somebody else is trying to use his credentials.

Comment: AFAIK, the only failsafe way to do this is to require users to log out. If they close the browser, they'll be locked out for (at most) 10 minutes. You could also check into keepalive [http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html]